# Vuex: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have set up a store in vue.js and can access the state parameters in the computed part of a compoenent:

```
computed: {
    BASE_URL () {
    return this.$store.state.BASE_URL;  
  }
```

However, when I try to access the store in the methods of the same component:

```
  methods: {

    register: function () {
          axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/web/register", {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password,
          email: this.email
        }).then(function(data){
          this.$store.commit('saveToken', data.token);
          console.log('token is set to:',  this.$store.state.token)
        });
    }  
 },
```

I get this error at the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of
>   undefined

I have also tried `$store` without `this` but get the same error.

What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you registered vuex in your application? `Vue.use(Vuex)`

Comment: Yes, I did. As I said, the vuex is accessible in the `computed` part of the component but not in the method's promise.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're using a javascript function instead of an arrow function.
Try this and it should work.

```
 methods: {
    register () {
          axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/web/register", {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password,
          email: this.email
        }).then( (data) => {
          this.$store.commit('saveToken', data.token);
          console.log('token is set to:',  this.$store.state.token)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Fantastic. This solved the issue. But why I can not use vanilla JS in the promise?

Comment: function have their own 'this' instance so when you call this you get the instance of the function your inside in and not the vue instance. 

The typical solution to this in vanilla javascript is to create a temporary variable outside the function then use it inside the function. 
e.g 

var self = this; 

register: function () {
    self.$store.commit();
}

Comment: FYI, arrow functions are also *"vanilla"* JavaScript.

Comment: @Phil thanks for the information didn't know that the tutorial I learned it from is wrong about that.